# How to make Universal Feed Parser only parse feeds?

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm trying to get content from external feeds on my Django web site with [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/). I want to have some user error handling, e.g. if the user supplies a URL that is not a feed. When I tried how feedparser responds to faulty input, I was surprised to see that feedparser does not throw any Exceptions at all. E.g. on HTML content, it tries to parse some information from the HTML code, and on non-existing domains, it returns a mostly empty dictionary:

```
{'bozo': 1,
'bozo_exception': URLError(gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'),),
'encoding': 'utf-8',
'entries': [],
'feed': {},
'version': None}
```

Other faulty input manifest themselves in the `status_code` or the `namespaces` values in the returned dictionary.

So, what's the best approach to have sane error checking without resorting to an endless cascade of `if .. elif .. elif ...`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acoording to `feedparser` documentation, in the [Bozo Detection](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/bozo.html) section:

> Universal Feed Parser can parse feeds whether they are well-formed XML or not. However, since some applications may wish to reject or warn users about non-well-formed feeds, Universal Feed Parser sets the bozo bit when it detects that a feed is not well-formed.

(In my opinion, it's not a very good practice to catch all exceptions and return them in another form, but that's just the way it works since "applications may just warn about non-well-formed feeds".)

So, after trying to parse a feed at any URL, you may check for the "bozo bit" and re-raise the corresponding exception:

```
f = feedparser.parse('http://example.com')
if f.bozo:
    raise f.bozo_exception
```

You may handle the exception according to the type and message, or by making assertions on other attributes of the object returned by `feedparser.parse` (such as: `f.feed` must be non-empty, `f.status` must equal 200, `f.entries` must be non-empty, `f.version` must be a valid feed format version, etc.), whatever seems most reasonable to your application.

Comment: Thanks! The `version` attribute provides more or less what I need to decide if I accept a resouce as a feed.